# Visual Studio/TFS: How to Remove Rollback From Pending Changes?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs-2015

I would like to ask how can I undo a rollback that I have in my "pending changes"?

Example:

1. In my pending changes I have many updates
2. Next I went to history and did a rolledback for one changeset from 2 weeks ago.
3. In Team Explorer I see:  [FileXYZ.cs][edit, rollback]
4. FileXYZ.cs contains other changes that are not related to the rollback
5. Now I want to "undo" rollback as if I have never wanted to do it.  In other words I want that the rollback does not take place when I check in the pending changes.  However I want that the changes in this file that were not related to the rollback are checked in.
   I do not want to do simply "undo" on a file as I will loose other changes.  I want to undo rollback for this particular changeset.

Any advice,

Learner.For.Ever

Comment: 1) I tried to find a command in IDE what would remove rollback. However I could not find any.  2) I see that rollback updates are not in the file so I guess they will be applied at the time of checkin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the file should be changed to reflect the rollback, so you may need to check that you do made the rollback successfully.

Second, there isn't anyway to undo the rollback in your case since you didn't check in the pending changes before you roll back and VS does not record these information either. So even the changes for the rollback is known, there isn't any information recorded about the changes you made before roll back, so it cannot be restored.

Comment: Thank you Eddie for confirmation.  Learning something new everyday :)